# How to disable dark theme in Android Pie?(Pre Android 10)

Tags: android

Dark Mode official support came in android 10, but we have dark mode option in Android pie and some pre android 10 MIUI as well.
As the app doesn't support dark mode, I want it disabled.
Using the below options, it works fine from API 29 but not before that.

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="p">false</item>
```

&

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

&

```
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
```

Comment: after adding this "android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
" in your style also add background color to root view in all XML layouts. Because in some device might can show dark theme if dark mode is enable in device. So add background color in root view for all XML layout.

Comment: android:forceDarkAllowed="false" dosen't help and adding background to all XML dosen't look like a solution

Comment: I know adding background to XML dosen't seems solution but in some case/some device it will show dark theme. Delete night theme XML and also add  forceDarkAllowed false and add that style in manifest > application tag.

Answer (score 2):

**Change Theme:**

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppparent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

**to**

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**If you not require night mode than  deleted 'themes.xml (night)**

Comment: I am already using <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"> , I don't have DayNight theme in my app

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you can programmatically do as you like using the below code:

```
if (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
      //update UI          
} else {
      //update UI
}
```

Comment: In the device I am testing , it skips this test as well

Comment: Which device are you using to test?

Comment: realme c1 with Android pie, This test works fine in Android 10 devices

Answer (score -1):

Change your theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`

Call this Below Method only in onCreate of your Application.

Make Sure that to mention your Application class in your manifest file

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: Have u tried it in android pie bcz i have already tried this and doesn't work, as i have mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: @PrateekKumar Its working in Android Pie, Please share more information

Answer (score -1):

- Change value in `themes.xml`

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.DarkModeDisableForce" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <!-- Disbale Dark Mode. -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

note :

1. Use `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` as parent
2. Change value item `colorSecondary`, `colorSecondaryVariant`, `colorOnSecondary`. (Optional)
3. Add `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>` in parent style item

---

-For API 29 (android 10)
** First, add style.xml in res/values-v29/styles.xml
** use this code in style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBackground</item>  <!-- use yours -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBackground</item><!-- use yours -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_support</item><!-- use yours -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/test_transition</item><!-- use yours -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Have u tried it in android pie bcz i have already tried this and doesn't work, as i have mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: I update the answer, tested in android 10, and its work.

Comment: Android 10 is not the problem at all, problem is in Android pie,The official support for dark theme came in android 10

Comment: add the sytles.xml in this path res/values-night-v21/styles.xml